# Can you insert native layout in flutter layout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a need. I need to insert advertisements in the list. The advertisement is an Android view. So what do I need to do? I hope you can help me. Thank you.
Views are a list, blue is a flutter view, and red should be an Andorid view

[image]

Comment: Yes but this is a difficult task to do. But there are official plugins for adds including.

Comment: This article may solve the problem. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6